# How to mock when ArrayList<Integer> in method argument?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

MyClass with one static method

```
MyClass {
     public static String myStaticMethod(HttpResponse httpResponse, ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
      //Some Business logic
      return "someString";
    }
```

MyWorkerClass

```
MyWorkerClass {
    
    public void myWorkerMethod  throws MyCustomException{
      //Some Business Logic
      MyClass.myStaticMethod(httpResponse, list);
      //Some more business logic
      }
    }
```

Writing test case to test one method of MyWorkerClass

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
    public class MyWorkerClassTest {
        @Test(expected = MyCustomException.class)
        public void myWorkerMethodTest() throws MyCustomException{
          //prepare required
          mockStatic(MyClass.class);
          when(MyClass.myStaticMethod(any(HttpResponse.class), any()).thenThrow(MyCustomException.class); //TARGET LINE
        
          MyWorkerClass objectMyWorkerClass = new MyWorkerClass();
          objectMyWorkerClass.myWorkerMethod();
         
         }
       }
```

When using **any()** as 2nd argument for ArrayList<Integer> at **TARGET LINE** then mocking is not working.
And getting compilation error if replacing any() with **anyList()** at TARGET LINE.

Comment: You have a ton of problems here. (1) Use `List`, not `ArrayList` for your parameter. (2) In general, treat `List` as a value and just use a real one instead of mocking it. (3) Mocking static methods is a serious smell and unnecessary starting with Java 8; either the static method is a _pure function_, in which case its implementation is an internal detail that you shouldn't interfere with, or you should be specifying it as a `BiConsumer<HttpResponse, List<Integer>>` or similar, which you can easily lambda up in a test.

Comment: Actually code has been written by someone else previously, so I don't want to change, but even I change method parameter to List<Integer> instead of ArrayList<Integer> and trying mocking like below didn't work.

when(MyClass.myStaticMethod(any(HttpResponse.class), any()).thenThrow(MyCustomException.class); //TARGET LINE
                               OR 
when(MyClass.myStaticMethod(any(HttpResponse.class), any(List.class)).thenThrow(MyCustomException.class); //TARGET LINE